# Opening a program or installed software from Terminal?

Tags: command-line

I need to know the command to open a program or software in terminal. The name of the program is `youtube-dl`

Comment: How did you install `youtube-dl`? Did you try to open terminal and just type `youtube-dl`?

Answer (score 2):

youtube-dl is a script with no graphical interface, so you run it in a terminal.

> youtube-dl is a small command-line program to download videos from YouTube.com and a few more sites. It requires the Python interpreter, version 2.6, 2.7, or 3.2+, and it is not platform specific. It should work on your Unix box, on Windows or on Mac OS X. It is released to the public domain, which means you can modify it, redistribute it or use it however you like.

```
youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]
```

see https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme for detailed instructions including examples of usage.

If you did not install it from the repos,

```
chmod a+x /path/to/youtube-dl
/path/to/youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Youtube-dl is a youtube download software. It's a command line utility, so you can't "open" it and it doesn't have a GUI: you'll have to run it as command, like this:

`youtube-dl video_URL`

If you want a GUI alternative, I recommend 4k Video Downloader:

http://www.4kdownload.com

Answer (score 0):

If it is installed, you should be able to just type youtube-dl and (at least) a URL. youtube-dl needs to know what to download. Easiest is to copy-paste it from a browser or something like that. When you paste into a Terminal window, use your mouse, or press Ctrl+Shift+V instead of the normal Ctrl+V.

If you get an error-message saying "no such file or directory", the program isn't installed. Reinstall it from Ubuntu Software Center or with apt-get in the Terminal (if you're familiar with that).

Now, if you just type:

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?somecode
```

it will download the video to the directory you're in. It's a good idea to move to the directory you want it in. So before downloading, type `cd ~/Videos` (if you want it in the Videos directory.
Alternatively, you can right-click a Files window, that you have displaying your desired directory, and click `Open in Terminal`. That'll open a Terminal window in the right place.

youtube-dl seems like a really powerful program, and it links into ffmpeg, that is another really powerful video converter. They can be a bit intimidating, but youtube-dl can be used just by giving it links as well - never mind the intimidating manual pages :)